# Applying \MakeUppercase on \makebox makes text disappear

Tags: capitalization, box, uppercase

Here is a MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makebox[4cm][l]{This is a test.}

\MakeUppercase{\makebox[4cm][l]{This is a test.}}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Paragraph with text and paragraph with missing text]

The logs don’t show any errors or warnings.

Why does this happen and how can I make the text in the second paragraph appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I share my solution here. I hope it's usefull for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[4cm][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\makebox[4cm][l]{This is a test 1.}

\MakeUppercase{%
    \mybox{This is a test 2.}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\makebox[4cm][L]{THIS IS A TEST.}


\end{document}
```

which produces an empty page (apart from the page number)

The problem is that `\makebox` uses a very compressed test to check the `[l]`, `[r]`, `[c]` option and in the case that it's an unexpected value like `L` then rather than give a warning, or error, or default to `[c]` it silently discards all the content.

In 1993 we were rather short on token memory to add extra checks but now this looks like a bug.

This would make `\makebox` log

```
LaTeX Warning: Unexpected alignment L on input line 18.
```

then act as `[c]` producing

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@imakebox[#1][#2]#3{%
  \@begin@tempboxa\hbox{#3}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%       support calc
    \hb@xt@\@tempdima{%
     \expandafter\ifx\csname bm@#2\endcsname\relax\bm@c
     \@latex@warning{Unexpected alignment #2}%
     \else\csname bm@#2\endcsname
     \fi}%
  \@end@tempboxa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\makebox[4cm][L]{THIS IS A TEST.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `\@ifundefined` be more standard?

Comment: @JosephWright possibly, but since it's going to be using raw `\csname` in the false case anyway the higher level version didn't seem to gain a lot

Comment: @JosephWright `\cs_if_exist_use:cF{bm@#2}
      {\bm@c\@latex@warning{Unexpected ~alignment ~#2}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the "l" inside the brackets is being made uppercase, too.

I would advise putting `\MakeUppercase` inside the box, rather than outside it.

Comment: I had even read this in the [unofficial LaTeX reference manual](https://latexref.xyz/dev/latex2e.pdf#216) but it completely went over my head… By the way, would there be any way to *still* use `\MakeUppercase` outside `\makebox`? For my real purposes I cannot use it inside.

Comment: @donjuardo It is possible to use `\MakeUppercase{\makebox[4cm][\MakeLowercase{l}]{This is a test.}}` to avoid this particular problem. That said, I have personally never needed to use \makebox, ever---what are you trying to do that requires it?

Comment: Don't you get an error?

Comment: @cfr Oddly, no, there is no error with any variant I have tried.

Comment: Could you expand this a bit? E.g. explain what `\makebox` does if the argument is unknown. Lots of people would understand changing the `l` to `L` is problematic, but most commands people are familiar with will either do something different, use a default or throw an error.

Comment: @karlh Different compiler? `pdflatex` won't compile with that line. `! Argument of \MakeLowercase    has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.176 ...4cm][\MakeLowercase{l}]{This is a test.}}
                                                  
? `

Comment: I agree this sounds increasingly like an xy-problem ....

Comment: @cfr pdflatex, xetex, and luatex all worked without complaint for me using his original post.

Comment: I meant, if I use `\MakeUppercase{\makebox[4cm][\MakeLowercase{l}]{This is a test.}}` which you suggested above, then I get an error.

Comment: @karlh This is what I’m trying to do: https://pastebin.com/raw/2XMH2yXi. Specifically, I want the indentation of the section, subsection, and subsubsection titles to be vertically aligned. I also get an error with `\MakeLowercase{l}` in both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr The `\MakeLowercase` variant works for me without complaint with all three options, too.

Comment: @cfr I took a peek at the definition of `\makebox`; I think this is "OK" because the macro that ultimately gets called, inside `\@imakebox`, is called with `\csname bm@#2\endcsname`; if bm@L, in this case, is not defined, then it will be set to `\relax` by the `\csname...\endcsname` logic, which will do nothing, as observed. (I think?)

Comment: That makes sense of the original case, but it doesn't explain why your modified version works for you. Version difference?

Comment: One could do `\makeatletter \let\bm@L\bm@l \makeatother` as a quick hack to allow `\makebox` inside the `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: @karlh `\makebox[4cm][\MakeLowercase{l}]{This is a test.}` does not work in a current LaTeX.

Comment: @DonHosek I think we should just fix makebox to default to `[c]` on unknown not default to discarding content silently.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are correct: there is no error using "LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5" (installed with TeX Live 2022); there IS an error using "LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1" (installed with TeX Live 2023, and used currently on Overleaf). Odd.